# how to merge buttons for each images in gallery?

Tags: android, image, button, merge, gallery

I have created a gallery, and it displays a lot of images in a horizontal view.

I need 3 buttons for each image below it. I don't know how to create this.

How can I achieve this layout?

This is my expected design:

[image]

Comment: If 3 button for each, then you should put that button out of gallery. Else put button the Item xml used in gallery.

Comment: actually the 3 buttons name is 1.profile 2.audio 3.video....the audio and video is differ from each images....so i need this format. my client also asking this format.....plz help me...

Comment: Then put 3 button below the gallery in your XML and simply use that. Whats the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a custom `ListView`, and the layout for each element has the image and the buttons. To do that, you need to subclass `BaseAdapter` and inject this adapter in your `ListView`.

```
final BaseAdapter myCustomAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(this);
final ListView gallery = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
gallery.setAdapter(myCustomAdapter);


public class GalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ....
    implements the class
    ....
}
```

Your `getView` method in the adapter would spawn the layout for individual item, and fill it dynamically with what you want.